# How to check an undefined JavaScript value in Facebook?

Tags: javascript, facebook, undefined

In normal JavaScript, I can check either

```
if (i == undefined)

or

if (i === undefined)
```

or the "typeof".

However, within Facebook, it will have the `api_key` appended as the prefix in undefined.

That is, it will become

```
if (a12345_i == a12345_undefined)
```

which is NOT undefined.

So, what can I do to find out if the variable is undefined or not?

---

Well, thanks for all answers, but I think I should emphasize one thing. I have no problem to detect the null value in a normal JavaScript environment. The probem I face is when it is with Facebook as an [FBML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_features#FBML) application.

Comment: I would suggest >> if (!x) { ... } << Except in cases where there is a semantic difference between ""/0/null/undefined (of which I find few, but they do exist) this should work well.

Answer (score 1):

typeof(var) returns a string, you should be checking:

```
typeof(var) == 'undefined'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
if (i == null) or if (i === null)
if (i == '') or if (i === '')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `x == null`, which will check for `null` or `undefined`.  However, the check you do should work.  While `a12345_undefined` doesn't *look* like `undefined`, it is.  For instance, this would work just as well:

```
var notDefined;
if (x === notDefined) { // ...
```

As long as you never assign anything into the variable `undefined` (which becomes `a12345_undefined`) you should be fine.  `undefined` is just a normal variable in JavaScript, it just starts with `undefined` value.  You could use any variable without a value as a comparison for `undefined`.

Hope that makes sense.